# How to get itunes album songs of itunes api

Tags: java, api, itunes

I can get album songs by

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=115255&entity=song
this id=115255 is the collectionId

I use https://itunes.apple.com/hk/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json get album info

but can't get collectionId, only get itunesId.
so i can't use that link to get album songs.

Have other ways to get album songs of itunes api?